# how do i create an Object.prototype clone

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, prototype-chain, prototype-oriented

I have an incomplete clone of `Object.prototype`, made to the best of my knowledge, can you show me how to finish it!?

### The Code

```
function duplicate_object_prototype(){
    var aRef=[
        '__defineGetter__',
        '__defineSetter__',
        '__lookupGetter__',
        '__lookupSetter__',
        'constructor',
        'hasOwnProperty',
        'isPrototypeOf',
        'propertyIsEnumerable',
        'toLocaleString',
        'toString',
        'valueOf',
        '__proto__'
    ];

    var clone = Object.create(null);

    for(var i in aRef){
        var ref = aRef[i];
        var pro = Object.prototype[ref];
        clone[ref] = pro;
        Object.defineProperty(clone,ref,{
            writable:false,
            enumerable:false,
            configurable:false
        });
    };

    console.log('clone:',clone);

    return clone;
}
```

### The Concept

Create the clone, then:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,'str',{get:function(){
    return JSON.stringify(this);
}})
```

Because, through inheritance, `Array.prototype` now has the `str` property, configure `Array`'s prototype chain to point to the clone when it should point to `Object.prototype`

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(Array.prototype, clone);
```

### The Logic

Now `Array` points to the clone, no modifications to `Object.prototype` will be inherited by any `Array` instance!

Comment: i think it's a bad idea in general, but it would be better to iterate the proto and gather names dynamically instead of white-listing them. that way you won't miss new additions or bind things that got removed. also, the  Object.defineProperty() in your 2nd block does not bind any value...

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve that inheritance or copying of an object won't already solve?

Comment: @dandavis: probably is a bad idea, i'm just testing my understanding of the proto system. ps: the white-list is only the base/non-enumerable's which can't be picked up if iterated if i remember right, hence the list.

Comment: @jfriend00: the problem **IS** prototype inheritance! it's a fu*&in nuisance, why can't they proclaim a different classification for `{}` as they have `[] '' 123 fun(){}`. i want to say `a={};Object.prototype=...;` and only `a` has said property not every other god damn classified object!

Comment: @LostInCyberSpace - you still haven't described what problem you're really trying to solve.  It's hard for us to help when we don't know the actual problem.  Right now, this appears to be the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you're describing issues with your solution without describing the actual problem you're trying to solve.  It's a very inefficient way to get help and precludes many other possibly better solutions than what you're trying.

Comment: you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype)`

Comment: if you want to extend custom objects, use Object.create() to move methods to the prototype where the new object's prototype or own properties can over-rule the methods passed to Object.create()

Comment: @jfriend00: my apologies. i simply want to add a set of properties to `Object.prototype` to use on objects(`{}`) in javascript whilst avoiding them leaking into other 'objects' such as arrays, elements, etc, via inheritance. i figured i could do that by re-directing the proto-chain to the cloned object with no modifications...

Comment: Why don't you add the actual goal of what you're doing (with some examples of how you want it to work) to your question and I suspect folks can come up with a solution.  It sounds to me like you're trying to add something to a base object and have it only affect instances of the base object without affecting derived objects.  It isn't the prototype that's messing you up, it's the concept of inheritance.

Comment: think i'll leave that for the next post! will give me time to think it through. one last time though: `o = {}; o.__proto__ === Object.prototype; a = []; a.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype`, i want to say `a.__proto__.__proto__ === Clone`. i perfectly understand the concept of inheritance, i just want to redirect the inheritance chain

Comment: i would offer that a regular textbook constructor will give you plain objects with custom methods, and still that inherits from Object.prototype, without breaking things or re-wiring low-level interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand very much what you are attempting to do, but you can clone `Object.prototype` like this:

```js
var proto = Object.prototype,
    clone = Object.create(null),
    props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto);
for(var i=0; i<props.length; ++i)
    Object.defineProperty(clone, props[i],
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proto, props[i])
    );
Object.freeze(clone);
```

Comment: cheers dude, i'll check it out! i suppose what i'm trying to do is unimportant, just needed to know how to clone 'ob.proto'

Comment: const clone = Object.defineProperties({}, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(fromObject));